# How to erase endpoints of lines in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Hey guys i'm from Viet Nam so my English is not good, forgive me if my words confuse you.

I have some lines with 1 pixel wide (after i skeletonize the binary image). How can I make a loop that erase all the endpoints of curves until there is no pixel that connected in all eight directions is more than two? (I just want to keep the longest line). Thank you for your help :(

Here is the thinned image link:
[image]

I'm trying to determine the length of shrimp using image processing. My idea is first thresholding the image, then thinning the object to make a curve represent for the lenght of object, finally measure the lenght of that curve.
This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology
from skimage import io

kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
kernel2 = np.ones((30,30), np.uint8)

img_ori = cv2.imread("0523.1212.06b.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img_ori,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold the image
ret,mask = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel2)
#closing_display = cv2.resize(closing, (605,645))
#cv2.imshow("Closing", closing_display)

# Erase small objects
cnts = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 5500:
        cv2.drawContours(closing, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)
closing_display = cv2.resize(closing, (605,645))
cv2.imshow("Shimp Detecting", closing)

# Determine contours
contours, hierachy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#Thinning
thinned = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(closing)
thinned_display = cv2.resize(thinned, (605,645))

#Draw contours on thinned
cv2.drawContours(thinned, contours, -1, (321, 100, 100), 2)
cv2.imshow("Thinned Image", thinned)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post the code you use to generate the skeletonized version? It would make helping you easier.

Comment: What is the expected output for the attached image ?

Comment: @JohannesAck I'm trying to determine the length of shrimp using image processing. My idea is first thresholding the image, then thinning the object to make a curve represent for the lenght of object, finally measure the lenght of that curve.
This is my code:

Comment: @ZdaR I want to erase all branching lines, just keep the longest line (of each object)